# Is www redirection (301) essential or not?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, no-www

I am new to SEO, and I have a website like StackExchange. I found one thing remarkably about my site is that `www` redirection (301) is not active. Is it essential?

Comment: Stack Exchange does use www redirects. They redirect www to non www.

Comment: For the benefit of others, this original question has been modified significantly making my answer not seem as relevant.

Comment: On a side note, and slightly OT, if you count social networks as a part of your SEO plan, make sure to use 301 as you write and not 302 (temporary) as Google+ and others does not load image resources properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`www` is just a subdomain. A website owner will normally make the decision whether they want their domain to be `domain.com` or `www.domain.com`.

If your website resolves to both the `no-www` version and the `www` version of your domain, then these are essentially two different URL's that your website is on so potentially causing duplicate content which is best to avoid and URL canonicalisation being the process of selecting the best/original URL of this particular content.

On an Apache server, you can implement your `www` canonicalisation 301 redirects in the root *.htaccess* like below:

This one removes all `www` from URL's:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This one forces all `www` in URL's:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^decodinghinduism.in$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.decodinghinduism.in/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have something to redirect, then yes, otherwise, it's not.

By that I mean, that just doing the `no-www` to `www` is important, but not essential. Plus most hosting places already do that for you.

In any case, it's a good practice to redirect the `no-www` to `www` or viceversa.

Comment: Thanks Patoma. My hosting provider is not doing 303 redirection. Can I do it manually ?

Comment: You mean the 301. Yes you can, no problem, in yout .htaccess, you can follow some of the [tutorials on this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=htaccess+redirect+non+www+to+www)

Comment: "most hosting places already do that for you" - I have never come across a host that does this redirection for you.

Comment: ehostpros use to do it, I don't know right now since they changed name but to me it looks like some body bought the company, many things have changed. Godaddy use to do it, I had 2 sites hosted there a few years a go and both options worked for me. In 1&1 we have a few clients plus our own company site hosted and we didn't set the redirections and they work. In web related forums I have read the same information about some other hosting companies that do the same, although I can't tell you which ones right now